# Mongoose/MongoDB - Some co-ordinate pairs no longer working with 2dsphere Indexes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a bit stumped on this one.

I'm saving geo data using Mongoose with the following schema:

```
var placeSchema = new Schema ({
    product: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Product', required:true},
        text : String,
    geo : { type: [Number], index: { type: '2dsphere', sparse: true } },
    geo_name : String,
  dateAdded: {type: Date, default: moment},
});
```

As recent as a couple weeks ago, all co-ordinate pairs were saving and being retrieved successfully. However, now, certain co-ordinate pairs are causing Mongo to complain with:

{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?: { _id: ObjectId('54affc5054096502ad086a81'), product: ObjectId('54af3f99c4528c296590426c'), geo_name: "Vancouver, BC, Canada", text: "", lastupdated: new Date(1420819536000), dateAdded: new Date(1420819536000), geo: [ 49.2827291, -123.1207375 ], __v: 0 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  code: 16755,
  err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can\'t extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?: { _id: ObjectId(\'54affc5054096502ad086a81\'), product: ObjectId(\'54af3f99c4528c296590426c\'), geo_name: "Vancouver, BC, Canada", text: "", lastupdated: new Date(1420819536000), dateAdded: new Date(1420819536000), geo: [ 49.2827291, -123.1207375 ], __v: 0 }' }

(the tricky thing is that some pairs that worked a few weeks ago now are hitting that error).

For example, these pairs work:

[ 33.7489954, -84.3879824 ] 
(which is Atlanta, GA, USA)

[ 41.8781136, -87.62979819999998 ] 
(which is Chicago, IL, USA)

And these do not and lead to the malformed geometry error:

[ 49.2827291, -123.12073750000002 ]
(which is Vancouver, BC, Canada)

[ 37.7749295, -122.41941550000001 ] 
(which is San Francisco, CA, USA)

Any ideas? I've tried formatting the 2dsphere field a bit differently, but still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the order of coordinate pairs for [MongoDB and GeoJSON is longitude, latitude](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) - not the other way around. The problem then is that anything beyond (-90, 90) for the second number is out of bounds.

Comment: d'oh! you're right. that was it. thanks for the 2nd set of eyes :)